# Cross domain requests and jQuery/AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I had read earlier that cross domain requests are not possible through AJAX (since XHR is bound to same origin policy)... Hence we use JSONP, which uses dynamic script injection (since script tag is not bound by same origin policy).

However, I was going through the jQuery AJAX documentation and saw one setting saying "crossDomain".

So, is Cross domain requests now supported through jQuery/AJAX? Is it the same as what we get through JSONP?

Comment: all that does is allow for jsonp requests, rather than killing the request from the get-go.

Comment: can u show with an example ?

Comment: It possible through CORS. See attached for server set up http://remysharp.com/2011/04/21/getting-cors-working/.  There is a good html5rocks article on client side setup.

Comment: Did you read the text against the "crossDomain" entry? If not then do so [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). It answers both your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I made a project that use cross domain requests. You have few examples.

It is [here](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/jQuery-cross-domain-requests), on Github.

Use this function in your client-side code (javascript):

```
function getHTML(url, callback){
    url = url.trim();

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(res) {
            var headline = res.responseText;

            if(headline === ""){
                callback("There was a problem with the page. Be sure that your url is correct.");
                return;
            }

            callback(null, headline);
        }
    });
}
```